# How to lock(passcode lock) iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, mobileme

For some security reasons, I wanted to lock my iPhone Screen through application. Can anybody tell me how it can be acheived?

I gone through many links & forums, but everyone says that it is not possible.
But if this is the case, can someone tell me how "Find iPhone" application (which is approved by Apple) can do a apsscode lock through application?
Here is link for Find iPhone application: [1]: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-my-iphone/id376101648?mt=8

At least, I wanted to know the logic behind it..

Answer (score 3):

"Find My iPhone" is not just approved by Apple, it is *by* Apple. Chances are it uses undocumented security features that are not available for us to use.

Comment: It seems like they are using "MobileMe" Services.. Correct me if I am wrong.. Can I use this service for developing my application?

Comment: Doubtful. You should file a feature request, and refrain from holding your breath.